# Add column to the Index using Include Clause without dropping the index in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to introduce a column to an existing index in the below format.

Existing index:

```
Create index idx_indexname on tablename(id)
```

My new index would be

```
Alter index idx_indexname on tablename(id) include (column1)
```

I want to add columns around 300 indexes in this way. Please suggest any dynamic approaches.

Note: Most of my indexes are falling under either unique (Non Clustered) / primary key (clustered indexes)

Comment: Does include column(s) would b same for all indexes

Comment: Yes most of the indexes would be same

Comment: You cannot add an included column to a clustered index because the column is included anyway (part of the data row, which is clustered index leaf node).  Use the `CREATE INDEX...WITH(DROP_EXISTING=ON) INCLUDE(Column1)` to rebuild the existing non-clustered index without a sort.

Comment: Do you want to add column to all existing indexes of all the tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, remove all of the clusterred indexes from the list. They're already the table itself, so all columns are autimatically included.
As for all the rest, you have to drop the index and recreate it.  You can use the drop_existing option, but it will essentially take the index offline.
Best to create the new indexes. Then remove the old. And rename using sp_rename to set the new indexes to the original index names.

Comment: Thanks you so much Amir

Answer (score 0):

You can drop and recreate an Index but you can not alter an index to add more columns.

Alter index is only used to set some properties of index.